# Scrapy If statement not evaluating in for loop

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to first mention that I have seen other questions on Stack Overflow similar to this and have attempted the resolutions recommended, however, each iteration replicates the problematic behaviour.

I am attempting to extract data from this website https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials in order to do some financial analysis however, the dump to my csv file is always empty.

I've tried to identify the issue in the scrapy shell and it seems like my "in values" never evaluates to true but I am not sure why because the initial response.xpath does print the table values.

The code is below. I appreciate any help, thank you all!

```
values = ["Sales/Revenue", "Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A", "Depreciation & Amortization Expense", "Gross Income", "SG&A Expense", "Research & Development", "EBIT after Unusual Expense", "Pretax Income", "Income Tax", "Net Income", "EBITDA"]

for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="crDataTable"]/tbody/tr[not(contains(@class,"thead"))]'):
        test = row.xpath('/td[1]//text()').extract()
        for i in values:
            if i in test:
                item['rowTitle'] = row.xpath('/td[1]//text()').extract()
                item['year1'] = row.xpath('/td[2]//text()').extract()
                item['year2'] = row.xpath('/td[3]//text()').extract()
                item['year3'] = row.xpath('/td[4]//text()').extract()
                item['year4'] = row.xpath('/td[5]//text()').extract()
                item['present'] = row.xpath('/td[6]//text()').extract()
                yield item
```